# uploading 1st and 2nd values of a map into the 1st and 2nd values of a vector pair

Tags: c++, vector, maps

Okay so I know from the title that my question sounds similar to others, and it is. But my problem is ever-so-slightly different and for some reason i keep getting errors when I search the web and try it other peoples ways. I have a maps(char, int) that consists of a bunch of characters and the number of times they appear in an unknown string. My program is counting and adding the characters & integers to the maps(char, int) just fine. What I'm having trouble doing is uploading those values into a vector(pair (char, int) ) 1 by 1 so I can ultimately sort them by their stored value and not their key value. here's the important part of my code.

```
int test2=0;

//my map is charCount and my vector is charVector

for (map<char, int>::iterator char_it = charCount.begin(); char_it != charCount.end();
++char_it) {

    charVector[test2].first = char_it->first;
    charVector[test2].second = char_it->second;
    test2++;

}
```

I think the for loop isn't even completing and I don't know why. I've even tried a for loop (without an iterator) in order to upload the maps.first and maps.second values 1 by 1. Nothing seems to be working. I don't know why I can't figure it out but I just can't

Comment: Has the vector been initialized with sufficient elements? You don't mention that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue might be that `vector` is empty, and `operator[]` doesn't provide any bounds checking (the member function `at()` does however.) If you were to use `at()` instead, it would throw a nice `std::out_of_range` error. With this assumption, I suggest you use `push_back` to add elements to your vector:

```
map<char, int> charCount = { { 'a', 1 }, { 'b', 2 }};
vector<pair<char, int>> charVector;

for (map<char, int>::iterator char_it = charCount.begin(); char_it != charCount.end();
++char_it) {
    charVector.push_back(make_pair(char_it->first, char_it->second));
} 
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < charVector.size(); i++)
    std::cout << charVector[i].first << " " << charVector[i].second << "\n";
```

If the `vector` isn't empty, and there truly is a one-to-one correspondence, then I suggest using `at()` so that you will get an exception if you go out of bounds.

```
try {
 for (map<char, int>::iterator char_it = charCount.begin(); char_it != charCount.end();
 ++char_it) {
    charVector.at(test2).first = char_it->first;
    charVector.at(test2).second = char_it->second;
    test2++;
 } 
} catch(std::out_of_range& ex)
{
  cout << "Out of range.\n";
}
```